# Django ajax returning null

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using Django to handle a form that sends a post request to a view and ajax is supposed to return that without refreshing the page.
Here's my Jquery with ajax:

```
$('.createFolder').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var folderName = $('#folderName').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'project:createFolder' %}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'folderName': folderName,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      alert(json);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's my view:

```
class createFolder(TemplateView):
template_name = "project/createFolder.html"

def post(self, request):
    folderName = request.GET.get('folderName')
    return JsonResponse(folderName, safe=False)
```

When running this the response I get displays "null". I'm not sure what is wrong here. Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Did the post method get call?

Comment: How can I check this? In the console I see this POST /project/bienbox/bucket/createFolder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making a POST request, you should fetch the data from `request.POST` instead of `request.GET`.

```
folderName = request.POST.get(‘folderName’)
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, this was so easy and I never spotted it. Thank you, it's working fine now!